# A representation of scaling operator for functions

Tags: functions, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, operator-algebras, eigenfunctions

Let us define a "scaling operator" $\hat{\Sigma}(\lambda)$ such that when it acts on any function $f(x)$, it gives $$\hat{\Sigma}(\lambda)f(x)=f(\lambda x).$$ Is it possible to represent the operator $\hat{\Sigma}(\lambda)$ as a differential (or integral) operator? If yes, what is it?

If $\phi(x)$ be an eigenfunction of $\hat{\Sigma}(\lambda)$, then $$\hat{\Sigma}(\lambda)\phi(x)=\phi(\lambda x)=s(\lambda)\phi(x).$$

From this, is it possible to find out how $s(\lambda)$ depends on $\lambda$ and the possible forms of $\phi(x)$?

Comment: What's the context here? "Any" function? Like on any domain, no regularity conditions, "any"?

Comment: @MartinArgerami For physics students like me, I mean, reasonably well-behaved functions (continuous, differentiable etc).

Answer (score 1):

The customary pseudodifferential realization of the dilation operator is
$$
e^{(\ln \lambda) ~~x\partial_x} ~f(x) = f(\lambda x),
$$
basically [Lagrange's translation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator#Functions_of_a_real_variable) where you set $\ln x =y$.

The eigenfunctions of dilations are then pure powers,
$$
\phi_\kappa(x) = c x^\kappa ,
$$
with $s(\lambda)=\lambda^\kappa$.